# Creating html elements through nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I've managed to successfully create HTML elements through JSON objects before, but now that I've changed my JSON objects to nested JSON, I am not able to reproduce the HTML elements accordingly. I am pretty new to programming so can anyone help me find out where I have gone wrong?

JSON File:

```
{  
  "ThreeG": [
    {
        "title":"Testing 1",
        "filePath":"https://example.com",
        "imagePath":"images/test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title":"Testing 2",
        "filePath":"https://example.com",
        "imagePath":"images/test2.jpg"
    }
   ]
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url : "TestFiles.json",
      type : "post", 
      contentType:"application/json",
      success : function(list){           
          var divCol  = "<div class='col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-md-5'>";
          var divWell = "<div class='well' style='position:relative'>";
          var divClose= "</div>";

          list.forEach(function(obj, index) {

            var title     = "<h4>"      + obj.ThreeG.title    + "</h4>";
            var linkStart = "<a href='" + obj.ThreeG.filePath + "' target='_blank'>" ;
            var image     = "<img data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Click to open data' src='" + obj.ThreeG.imagePath + "' height='100%' width='100%'/>"
            var linkEnd   =  "</a>";

            var div = divCol    +
            divWell     +
            title       +
            linkStart       +
            image       +
            linkEnd +
            divClose +
            divClose;

            console.log(obj);
           $("#test").append(div); 

           })
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `list` param in the success callback is an object with property / key `ThreeG`. So instead of `list.forEach`, you should do `list.ThreeG.forEach`, then each `obj` in the forEach callback will be the json object that you can use to create HTML elements.

```
list.ThreeG.forEach(function(obj, index) {
         console.log(obj); // { "title":"Testing 1", "filePath":"https://example.com", "imagePath":"images/test.jpg" } for the first object
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but it is not working and the console did not output anything

Comment: @nurul98 replace `list.forEach` with this in the above script

Comment: replace it with what?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? and is the list object a JSON string or a parsed javascript object (normally, it should be a parsed JS object, though)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {  
  "ThreeG": [
    {
        "title":"Testing 1",
        "filePath":"https://example.com",
        "imagePath":"images/test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title":"Testing 2",
        "filePath":"https://example.com",
        "imagePath":"images/test2.jpg"
    }
   ]
};

for(var i=0;i<obj.ThreeG.length;i++) {
var data = obj.ThreeG[i];//Take a reference here
console.log(data.title, data.filePath, data.imagePath);
}
```

You cannot say `obj.ThreeG.title` since `obj.ThreeG` is an `array`. You need to use `obj.ThreeG[0].title` and `obj.ThreeG[1].title` etc.

Do some looping as shown above.

Comment: May I ask, where do I put that for loop in my script?

Comment: @nurul98 Assuming `list` is also an array, you can do it inside the function `function(obj, index) {`.

Comment: @nurul98 What is `list`?

Comment: list is the data that I've sent to the ajax

Comment: @nurul98 `list` is the data that you `got` from ajax call not `sent`. What do you get when you do `console.log` on `list`?