# How to perform this dynamic Find and replace in Javascript over user generated data?

Tags: javascript, foreach, createelement, domparser, selectors-api

I have an app that allows user to generate text with HTML code in the following format:

```
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>
    
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
```

This is how it looks like in a browser:

[image: This is how it looks like in a browser]

Is there any way to replace what user generated with the one below, using javascript?

```
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1 <button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});">Save</button></h2>
    <h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2 <button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 2', output2: 'User generated text 2.1\nUser generated text 2.2\nUser generated text 2.3'});">Save</button></h2>
    <h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>
    
    
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3 <button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 3', output2: 'User generated text 3.1\nUser generated text 2.2'});">Save</button></h2>
    <h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
```

This is how the above would look like in a browser:

[image: This is how the above would look like in a browser]

The situation is very trickey because:

- All the texts surrounded by `<h2></h2>` and `<h3></h3>` tags are user generated.
- Users can generate any number of `<h2>` Texts followed by any or even zero number of `<h3>` texts.

Can you guys suggest any work around this using javascript?

Thanks

I would have tried

```
s.replace('<h2>', '<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1 <button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});">Save</button></h2>')
```

But it just isn't possible because the texts are dynamically generated and are unique each time.

Comment: So you're generating that entire HTML (including the `<h2>`) and then inserting the user's input between them? Is there a reason why you can't add the button in while you're generating the `h2` tags rather than trying to insert them after the fact?

Comment: The user's input text plus the HTML tag is directly coming from an AI response. I do not have any control over it.

Comment: @mendicant_bias ... Regarding all the provided answers, are there any questions left?

Comment: Yep, The one by mplungjan worked for me. Just a disclaimer, you have to load the code right before the page starts loading or at least the part where the javascript is being applied. I also used h2.class-name to apply it on the specific parts, not doing so will apply it throughout the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use regex or replace to change HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Just use DOM access

Here is the minimum safe way to create the object and embed it in a button

```js
const nextUntil = (element, selectors, filter = "*") => {
  const siblings = [element];
  let next = element.nextElementSibling;

  while (next && !next.matches(selectors)) {
    if (next.matches(filter))
      siblings.push(next);
    next = next.nextElementSibling;
  }

  return siblings;
};

document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(header => {
  const subs = nextUntil(header,'h2','h3')
  //console.log(subs)
  const object = {output1: subs[0].textContent,output2: subs.slice(1).map(ele => ele.textContent).join('\n')}
  header.innerHTML = `${header.textContent} 
    <button class="something" 
    onclick='bubble_fn_add_headers(${JSON.stringify(object)})'>Save</button>`;
}) 
  
const bubble_fn_add_headers = obj => console.log(obj);

/* I recommend the following instead of inline onclick

document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.something');
  if (!tgt) return; 
  bubble_fn_add_headers(tgt.dataset.content)
})

using this code for the data-attribute

    data-content='${
    JSON.stringify({ 
      "output1": subs[0].textContent, 
      "output2": subs.slice(1).map(ele => ele.textContent).join('\n')
    })}'
*/
```

```html
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1</h2>
<h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2</h2>
<h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
<h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>

<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3</h2>
<h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
```

Here is what you asked for. It is VERY BRITTLE and will blow up the first time a user enters a quote or a double quote

```js
const nextUntil = (element, selectors, filter = "*") => {
  const siblings = [element];
  let next = element.nextElementSibling;

  while (next && !next.matches(selectors)) {
    if (next.matches(filter))
      siblings.push(next);
    next = next.nextElementSibling;
  }

  return siblings;
};

document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(header => {
  const subs = nextUntil(header,'h2','h3')
  //console.log(subs)
  const string = `{output1: '${subs[0].textContent}, output2: '${subs.slice(1).map(ele => ele.textContent).join('\\n')}`
  header.innerHTML = `${header.textContent} 
    <button class="something" 
    onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers('${string}')">Save</button>`;
}) 
  
const bubble_fn_add_headers = obj => console.log(obj);

/* I recommend the following instead of inline onclick

document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.something');
  if (!tgt) return; 
  bubble_fn_add_headers(tgt.dataset.content)
})

using this code for the data-attribute

    data-content='${
    JSON.stringify({ 
      "output1": subs[0].textContent, 
      "output2": subs.slice(1).map(ele => ele.textContent).join('\n')
    })}'
*/
```

```html
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1</h2>
<h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2</h2>
<h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
<h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>

<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3</h2>
<h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
<h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks! It came pretty close

It's generating:

<button class="something" data-content="{&quot;output1&quot;:&quot;User generated Dynamic Data 1&quot;,&quot;output2&quot;:&quot;User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2&quot;}">Save</button>

How do I adjust the script to get this response instead?

<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});">Save</button>

Comment: Is there any other method besides removing JSON.stringfly?

Comment: Please see update. It should do what you want

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: Almost there!

It generated this:

<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({"output1":"User generated Dynamic Data 1","output2":"User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2"})">Save</button>

Can we replace those double quotes with single quotes just the way it's right below?

<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});">Save</button>

Also, the texts output1 and output2 aren't to be quoted.

Comment: We cannot easily do that - you will have quite some issues with nested quotes. You mean the keys. They are quoted when we stringify the object as we MUST do. Why are they not allowed to be quoted. What program would not allow valid JSON but allow invalid one?

Comment: This is the only way I'm afraid, I'm using an application that accepts button inputs in this particular format:


 onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});"

Comment: That is a very dumb application then. We can do what you want, but it will break the first time the user enters a quote or a doublequote

Comment: See update. Your version is the second version

Comment: Thanks! The second one worked. I'll refine user-generated text to that they won't be able to put quote or double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Consider generating the HTML elements dynamically from the user input, which is easier and more scalable:

1. Get user input value using [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. Store the input value in an array
3. Generate a list of "li" or "div", using [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[Working example is here.](https://playcode.io/1797489)

As for generating more complex/nested elements, [better approach would be to store data as JSON object, and render by referencing the keys.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430461).

Comment: You can post working code here using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 0):

## Loop over the headings with `querySelectorAll`

One solution would be to iterate over your content, extract the necessary text and generate the buttons dynamically, adding custom event handlers to each button.

If I understood the problem, this should work.

```js
const myHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

let el;
for (const h2 of myHeaders) {

    const output1 = h2.textContent;
    let output2 = [];
    el = h2.nextElementSibling;

    while (el && el.matches('h3')) {
        console.log(el.textContent);
        output2.push(el.textContent);
        el = el.nextElementSibling;
    }

    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.class = "something";
    btn.textContent = "Save";
    btn.addEventListener('click', ev => {
        bubble_fn_add_headers({ output1, output2: output2.join('\n') });        
    });    
    h2.append(btn);
}

function bubble_fn_add_headers(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

However, I would question a number of things about the system that generated this output in the first place.
One thing is that your HTML seems to have very little structure.
Perhaps each `<h2>` element could be enclosed in a `<section>` for example. This would make the task a lot easier because you could loop over the sections and extract the `<h2>` and `<h3>` elements using simple queries.

Comment: Yeah, It's an AI-generated structure, I have zero control over it and can't add additional tags.

Comment: Thanks Graeme.

It added <button>Save</button>

I'm looking to add:

<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: 'User generated Dynamic Data 1', output2: 'User generated text 1.1\nUser generated text 1.2'});">Save</button>

Is there any work around that?

Answer (score 0):

A single function does the trick.

It has to be passed as callback to the [**`forEach` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) of a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which got obtained by [**querying all `H2` elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) from the before [**parsed html markup**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString#parsing_xml_svg_and_html).

Said function creates and inserts a button element with inline-handler code which got collected/accumulated from each header-related text-content.

With the mutation of each `H2` element node, the before parsed html document gets mutated as well. Thus, after having processed each `H2` element one can do both, continue working with the parsed and mutated DOM and/or reading its `innerHTML` which should be equal to the final markup the OP is looking for.

```js
const htmlDoc = (new DOMParser)
  .parseFromString(sourceMarkup, 'text/html');

htmlDoc
  .body
  .querySelectorAll('h2')
  .forEach(insertButtonWithHeaderContentHandler);

const targetMarkup = htmlDoc.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = targetMarkup;

console.log({ targetMarkup });
```

```css
:root { font-size: .8em; }
body { margin: 0; }
h2, h3 { width: 30%; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%; width: 70%; }
```

```html
<script>
function insertButtonWithHeaderContentHandler(
  node, idx, nodeList
) {
  let nextNode;
  let subContent = '';

  while (
    (node = node.nextSibling) &&
    (node !== nodeList[idx + 1])
  ) {
    subContent += node.textContent;
  }
  node = nodeList[idx];

  subContent = subContent
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s*\n+\s*/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/^\n+|\n+$/g, '')
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')

  const inlineHandlerCode =
    `bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: "${ node.textContent }", output2: "${ subContent }" });`

  const elmButton = document.createElement('button');

  elmButton.textContent = 'Save';
  elmButton.classList.add('something');
  elmButton.setAttribute('onclick', inlineHandlerCode);

  node.appendChild(elmButton);
}

const sourceMarkup = `
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>
    
    
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
`;

function bubble_fn_add_headers({ output1, output2 }) {
  console.log({ output1, output2 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex for this. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkt217/4a1wckLv/) for more details.

Code::

```
let content = `
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 1</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 1.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 1.2</h3>


<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 2</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 2.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.2</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 2.3</h3>
    
<h2>User generated Dynamic Data 3</h2>
    <h3>User generated text 3.1</h3>
    <h3>User generated text 3.2</h3>
`;

// -- find text between a <h2> tag
const stext = content.match(/(?<=<h2>).*(<\/h2>)|(?<=<h3>).*(?=<\/h3>)/g);
console.log('stext:: ', stext);

let output1 = '', output2 = '', count = 0;
stext.forEach(text => {
    if(text.indexOf('</h2>') > -1) {
        // -- every time a primary text is found update the user generated content. This will run 1 count behind the main counter
    if(count > 0) {
        content = content.replace(output1, `${output1}<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: '${output1}', output2: ${output2}});">Save</button>`)
    }
    // -- this is for primary text
    output1 = text.replace('</h2>', '');
    output2 = ''; // -- resetting this
    count++;
  }
  else {
    // -- this is for sub-text
    output2 += `${text}\n`; 
  }
});
content = content.replace(output1, `${output1}<button class="something" onclick="bubble_fn_add_headers({output1: '${output1}', output2: ${output2}});">Save</button>`)

document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: If you click the button marked `[<>]` you can post running code here. However it is not recommended to process HTML using regex

Comment: Thanks! It brought the result I was seeking, but for some reason, It removed all the default surrounding code of the page.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Change `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = content;` to the container of the H2s